# How do I support multiple top level namespaces in a single json schema document? This is for helm sub charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jsonschema, helm3

I know "namespace" isn't the right term, but I had trouble finding this use case explained in the json schema docs or online.

I use json schema for a helm sub chart. Without going into helm specifics this means this schema is going to be used to validate a yaml doc that looks like this (in the sub charts own project):

```
# values.yaml in mysubchart
propOne:
 derp: 123
 herp: abc
```

And also yaml docs that look like this (in the parent chart project):

```
# values.yaml in mysubchart
mysubchart:
    propOne:
     derp: 123
     herp: abc
```

So I have two docs i want to validate with the same schema. The only difference is one of the docs has a single top level field everything is nested under (`mysubchart:`)

Is it possible to support both docs with the same json schema? Helm will validate the schema with helm lint without issue, but I also want users to be able to point their editors to a json schema I publish to validate the values yamls in the parent chart and get autocomplete, etc.

EDIT

I tried this but it doesn't validate for either yaml doc:

```
{
    "$defs": {
        "mychart": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
            "title": "test",
            "description": "test",
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "propOne",
                "propTwo"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "propOne": {
                    "description": "sdkfjlsdfjlksdjf",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "propTwo": {
                    "description": "sdkfjlsdfjlksdjf",
                    "type": "string"
                },
            }
        },
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/mychart"
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "mychart": {
                    "$defs": "#/$defs/mychart"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It looks like this works for validating my first yaml doc:

```
"anyOf": [
    {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/mychart"
    }
]
```

But adding the second element with `properties` to try to validate the second doc screws it up and neither validates correctly

This works I was missing the required:mysubchart part of the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine multiple schemas with `oneOf`, and move the common elements into a definition referenced by both schemas:

```
  $defs:
    chart:
      type: object
      required: [ propOne ]
      properties:
        propOne:
          required: [ derp, herp ]
          properties:
            derp:
              type: integer
            herp:
              type: string
  type: object
  oneOf:
  - $ref: '#/$defs/chart'
  - required: [ mysubchart ]
    properties:
      mysubchart:
        $defs: '#/$defs/chart'
```

If you are using an implementation that only supports draft7 or earlier, then change `$defs` to `definitions`.

Combining schemas is covered at https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html.

Comment: Is the above the schema file? does json schema support yaml?

Comment: I tried this (see my edit) and it breaks validation for both yaml docs and does not seem to work